# Rigorous multivariate differentiation of integral with moving boundaries (Leibniz rule)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, multiple-integral

The [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), in its multivariate form, deals with differentiation of the following sort:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_{D(t)} F({\bf x}, t) \, d{\bf x} \, , \qquad D(t)\in \mathbb{R}^d \, .$$

I am looking for a fully rigorous formulation of this theorem, as well as a proper proof. So far, I could only find:

1. The one-dimensional case (see e.g., Courant calculus book).
2. Physics-flavored books, where the normal speed $v_n ({\bf x})$ is not defined (see e.g., [here](http://sgpwe.izt.uam.mx/files/users/uami/jdf/proyectos/Derivar_inetegral.pdf)). While insightful, this is not what I need.
3. Very abstract, measure theoretical versions of it.

**My question:** Could you please refer me to a multivariate-calculus statement and proof of this theorem?

**Update:** I searched most of the textbooks [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44522/theoretical-multivariable-calculus-textbooks?rq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43290/references-for-multivariable-calculus), but still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: For the case of $D_t$ a ball of radius $t$ see this question:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2767317/leibniz-rule-with-balls/2767682#2767682

Comment: Thanks @ChristianBlatter, but I was looking for the general case.