# Leibniz formula for integral with spherical coordinates in multi-dimensional space

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates, leibniz-integral-rule

Given $u: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ smooth enough and set $\bar{u}(r) = \int_{|x| = r}u(x)d\sigma$, with $x = \left(r, \sigma\right)$ is the spherical coordinate of $x$.
I have some differences in calculating $\frac{d^2}{dr^2} \bar{u}$.
From the Leibniz rule, we can have it for a ball ([Leibniz rule with balls](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2767317/leibniz-rule-with-balls)), but I don't know how to apply it for the spherical coordinate.
Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: See what you get for $n=2$ and $n=3$ to see the pattern.

Comment: We have $\overline{u}(r)=\int_{S^{n-1}(r)}u\,d\sigma_r=\int_{S^{n-1}}u(r\omega)\cdot r^{n-1}\,d\sigma(\omega)$, where $S^{n-1}(r)$  is the radius $r$-sphere, $d\sigma_r$ is the measure on this radius $r$ sphere, and $S^{n-1}$ is the unit sphere, with measure $d\sigma$. Now that the domain is fixed, I’m sure you can differentiate this result with respect to $r$ using the basic form of Leibniz’s integral rule, and the chain and product rules on the integrand.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you very much. It's done.